# Testing for ErrorKind from a Box<dyn Error>

Tags: rust

I've got this function that I want to test:

```rust
pub fn run(config: Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)?;
    // -- snip
    Ok(())
}
```

And this test:

```rust
#[test]
fn error_for_missing_file() {
    let error = run(Config {
        query: String::from("query"),
        filename: String::from("not_a_real_file.txt"),
    })
    .unwrap_err();

    let kind = error.kind(); // no method named `kind` found for struct `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` in the current scope
   // assert to follow
}
```

How can I get the `ErrorKind` from a Box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) doesn't have a `kind` method; it's a method of [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html). If you only have access to the base trait you won't be able to call it.

If you make that `Box<dyn std::error::Error>` a `std::io::Error` instead you'll have access to it. (And there's no need for a boxed trait object since `std::io::Error` is a concrete struct.)

Better yet, you can return a `std::io::Result<_>`, which is a `Result` type specialized to hold `std::io::Error`s:

```
use std::io;

pub fn run(config: Config) -> io::Result<()> {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)?;
    // -- snip
    Ok(())
}
```